# JPQL Query generates Incorrect syntax near 'cross' for Sybase

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpql, named-query

I have a named query that is generating cross joins for the calls to my Sybase 15 database. I think I need to reformat my query to use joins but cannot figure out the required syntax. The objects and their mappings are as below

## WorkflowDef

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_type_id", nullable = false)
private WorkflowType workflowType;
```

## WorkflowInstance

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_def_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private WorkflowDef workflowDef;
```

and my named query is

```
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkflowInstance.hasStatus", query = "SELECT wi.id FROM WorkflowInstance wi WHERE wi.deal.id = :dealId AND wi.workflowDef.workflowType.systemKey = :wfTypeName AND wi.status IN (:statuses)")
```

this throws the error

```
2015-01-26 16:27:24,237 DEBUG [http-8080-3] util.SQLStatementLogger - 
select
    workflowin0_.wf_instance_id as col_0_0_ 
from
    tbl_wf_instance workflowin0_ cross 
join
    tbl_workflow_def workflowde1_ cross 
join
    tbl_lkp_workflow_type workflowty2_ 
where
    workflowin0_.workflow_def_id=workflowde1_.workflow_def_id 
    and workflowde1_.workflow_type_id=workflowty2_.workflow_type_id 
    and workflowin0_.deal_id=? 
    and workflowty2_.name=? 
    and (
        workflowin0_.status in (
            ?
        )
    )
```

2015-01-26 16:27:24,238 TRACE [http-8080-3] type.NullableType - binding '60001972' to parameter: 1
2015-01-26 16:27:24,239 TRACE [http-8080-3] type.NullableType - binding 'CREDIT' to parameter: 2
2015-01-26 16:27:24,240 DEBUG [http-8080-3] type.EnumType - Binding '2' to parameter: 3
2015-01-26 16:27:24,277 WARN [http-8080-3] util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 102, SQLState: 42000
2015-01-26 16:27:24,278 ERROR [http-8080-3] util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Incorrect syntax near 'cross'.

I am using the following in my persistence unit

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

Comment: You have the generated SQL there. Have you tried executing it directly against the database? Try to figure out a bit more about what exactly is wrong with the query. (I don't have the Sybase 15 expertise to automatically know what is wrong with the query.) This may give you some insight into what needs to be done.

Comment: Hi dcsohl the problem is that sybase does not accept the cross join syntax. I believe this is a known issue however the bigger problem is that this should not be a cross join/ full outer join anyway so I think I have

Comment: ...a problem with either my mappings or named query syntax

Answer (score 1):

This is because of dialect, try changing the other version of dialect. 
e.g.  in hibernate.cfg.xml if you using Sybase...

Workaround is use the SybaseASE15Dialect instead of SybaseASEDialect

Comment: This helped me. I was using SybaseDialect which was generating cross joins which were not supported. Updating the same to SybaseASE15Dialect helped generate the queries with just joins and my JPQL queries starting working fine. Looks like a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `CROSS JOIN` syntax is not supported, but you can just remove the keywords `CROSS`. The semantics don't change.

Comment: Hi Rob, removing the keyword 'cross' still results in an error when running the query directly against the database...."Incorrect syntax near the keyword join". Also I still think that the JPA query should not be even attempting to generate a cross join but instead an inner join

Comment: sorry that should have been "Incorrect syntax near the keyword where".

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` is the same as `INNER JOIN`. The problem is that there is no `ON` clause which is required for ANSI-style joins. If you indeed want the Cartesian product, then just add `ON 1=1` for each `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it seems this was an issue with old hibernate libraries rather than the mappings defined on the entities. Upgrading the libraries is now resulting in correct sql being generated for the sybase back end.